# How to create list in appointment class and how to write test case?

Tags: java, oop

Implement a superclass Appointment and subclasses Onetime, Daily, and Monthly.
An appointment has a description (for example, “see the dentist”) and a date.
Write a method occurs On(int year, int month, int day) that checks whether the appointment occurs on that date.
For example, for a monthly appointment, you must check whether the day of the month matches, then fill an array of Appoint­ment objects with a mixture of appointments.
Have the user enter a date and print out all appointments that occur on that date.

```
public class Appointment {

    private String description;
    private Date date;

    public Appointment(String description, int day, int month, int year) 
        throws ParseException {
        this.description=description;
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        this.setDate(simpleDateFormat.parse(String.format("%d/%d/%d", day, 
        month, year)));

    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Your Appointment is : %s. On(date): ", 
        this.getDescription(), this.getDate()
                .toString());
    }

    public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day) throws 
        ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
        SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(String.format("%d/%d/%d", day, 
        month, year));

        return this.getDate().equals(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Have a look at [writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question).  Are you sure this is not homework?

Answer (score 0):

Make the `Appointment` base class abstract, together with the `occursOn` methods. Also delete the `date` variable, as some subclasses won't need that:

```
public abstract class Appointment {

    private String description;

    public Appointment(String description) 
        this.description=description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public abstract boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day) throws 
        ParseException;
}
```

Now we can start creating the subclasses, which will implement the `occursOn` method. For the `Onetime` subclass it will be basically the same as your original `Appointment` class, so I will not write that now. Instead, lets take a look at the `Monthly`, for example:

```
public class Monthly extends Appointment {

    private String description;
    private int onThisDay; //on this day of the month is the appointment

    public Appointment(String description, int onThisDay) {
        this.description=description;
        this.onThisDay = onThisDay;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    //override tostring as well
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Your " + description + " appointment is on the " +
        onThisDay + ". day of the month";
    }

    //implement our abstract method, month and year params have no importance here
    public boolean occursOn(int year, int month, int day) throws 
        ParseException {
        return day == onThisDay; //just check if day matches
    }
}
```

As to how to fill a list of appointments, here it is:

```
List<Appointment> appointments = new ArrayList<>();
//2 appointments for example
appointments.addAll(new Onetime("Doctor",2019,07,21), new Monthly("Dentist",11));
appointments.forEach(app -> System.out.println(app.toString())); //print all
```